# JavaScript - Regular Expression For Alpha/ Numeric combination

Tags: javascript, regex

Pardon my inexperience in Regex world.

I am trying to validate a expression which look like this : ***AB-4567*** or ***PK-1234***.
i.e. either set of 2 fix letters followed by a '-' and then digits with no constrain on length.

Few more valid examples:

> 1. AB-1234
> 2. AB-12
> 3. AB-54643564
> 4. PK-1
> 5. PK-341313
> 6. PK-133

So, it should start with either AB or PK then without any space hyphen and then any length of digits
I tried with  `/(AB)|(PK)[-][0-9]/` but it fails in following situation

1. ABPK-1213 (both set of prefix)
2. AB-R12U45N (alphabets in digits. either at start, middle or end)

I know I am missing something very basic but not able to solve it.

Comment: Thank you all for your help and wonderful explanation on the issue and alternatives. Appreciate your time.

Comment: Were all glad to help. If an answer worked for you please accept one and close the question.

Comment: It's shame that one can not mark multiple correct answer to reward repliers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first six examples

> `/^(AB|PK)-[0-9]+$`

If you want to include the other two possibility (ABPK-1213 , AB-R12U45N) try

> `/^(AB|PK|ABPK|PKAB)-[0-9A-Z]+$`

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there:

```
^(?:AB|PK)-[0-9]+$
```

Your alternation character `|` was in the wrong place. The way you had it, it meant "match `AB` OR match `PK` and all these other characters.

Comment: The anchors are also important, although you could use word boundaries instead.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld You're right. :) I used anchors without noticing that the original regex didn't have them.

Comment: Thank you Ron and ZX81 for your inputs.